# Using useMemo instead of React.memo syntax issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to make a demonstration of using React Hooks useMemo. I have working code that is as follows that does what I want:

```
const SpeakerCardDetail = React.memo(
  ({id,...
```

I found a [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14616) that shows that I could use syntax more like this but I can't figure it out exactly.

This is as far as I got:

```
const SpeakerDetail = React.useMemo(() => {
   ({ id,
```

Clearly not it though.  I do get that React.memo solves the problem but I do need to show useMemo in action and am hoping there is an alternative syntax that I can use.

Comment: wait what is it that you need to do? just any example of using `useMemo` ?

Comment: `React.memo` allows functional component to have same optimization as `PureComponent` provides for class-based components. `useMemo` is for memoizing function's calls inside functional component. It would be hard to replace one with another since they have different purposes.

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to get the same result as React.memo, which is that the return of the pure function is saved with memoization.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`React.memo` and `React.useMemo` are not equivalent at all (don't rely on naming similarity). Here's a quote from `React.memo` [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

> `React.memo` is a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

So it's a HOC that can optimize rendition of your component given that it renders the same output with the same properties.

`React.useMemo` on the other hand is more generic and [returns a memoized value](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

> Pass a “create” function and an array of dependencies. `useMemo` will
>   only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies (either `a` or `b`) has
>   changed.

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(
  () => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), 
  [a, b]
);
```

And while it can be hacked to be used instead of `React.memo`, it's not its purpose and it will add to the confusion more than it will help. `useMemo` is a hook and is subject to the [certain usage rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

And there's this warning as well:

> In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized
>   values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for
>   offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without
>   `useMemo` — and then add it to optimize performance.

Comment: Thanks. I've come to the same conclusion and was fooled by the naming. I'm using as my example now the resuilts of a sort before rendering.

Comment: Though, I have to say I stared at this example for a long time because it makes them feel somewhat the same.  https://codesandbox.io/s/7m03xn9wlx

Answer (score 41):

While `memo` is a HOC and `useMemo` is a hook, you can use them the achieve the same result.

For context, HOC is an older React pattern that has been used for many years with class-based and functional components alike. You can still use it today (there's no plan for deprecation).

Hooks is a relatively new concept (about a year) that enhances functional components and in many cases drastically [simplifies code](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation). That's why many developers are moving towards using hooks.

Anyway, both `memo` and `useMemo` take two arguments: a function and props. If none of the props change on subsequent re-renders, the function is not executed again and instead returns the previous result. This, in effect, replaces `shouldComponentUpdate` callbacks, with a purely functional approach.

With `memo`, your code would look like this:

```js
const SpeakerCardDetail = React.memo(
  (props) => <div>{props.name}</div>
)
```

With `useMemo`, you'd write:

```js
const SpeakerCardDetail = (props) => useMemo(() => <div>{props.name}</div>)
```

Notice that `useMemo` is used inside of your component function, while `memo` wraps the function.

More traditionally, `useMemo` could be written as:

```js
function SpeakerCardDetail(props) {
  return useMemo(
    () => <div>{props.name}</div>
  )
}
```

Now, the code above would re-render every time, making the `useMemo` function a bit useless. To make it work its magic, we need to add the second argument. (`memo` still works even without specifying the second argument but you can add it to customize it)

There's a slight difference in the format of the second argument. `memo` expects a function that compares previous and current props, just like `shouldComponentUpdate` does for class components.

```js
const SpeakerCardDetail = React.memo(
  (props) => <div>{props.name}</div>
,
  // return true if passing nextProps to render would return the same result as passing prevProps to render, otherwise return false
  (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.name === nextProps.name
)
```

`useMemo`, on the other hand, expects an array as the second argument. Whenever the values in the array change, the function would be executed again.

```js
function SpeakerCardDetail(props) {
  return useMemo(
    () => <div>{props.name}</div>
  ,
    [props.name]
  )
}
```

There's really no more magic than that. Both `memo` and `useMemo` are used to memoize the result of a function, the only difference is `memo` is a HOC (and can be used to wrap both class and functional components) which `useMemo` is a hook (and can only be used inside functional components).

Comment: Could you please suggest us which is better in way we can use both approach?

Comment: @Muhammad Neither is strictly better than the other. If you use class components then you have to use `memo`. If you use functional components with hooks, you might want to use `useMemo` (though, in this case, you could use `memo`, too). `useMemo` also has a more concise second argument. In the end, it's all just a matter of preference. Any difference in performance should be negligible.

Comment: When the component is inside a condition, with useMemo, you get the rendered fewer hooks than expected, so in that case I suppose memo is the only option.

Comment: The bottom line is, if you're comfortable with using hooks and you use them throughout your project, you might prefer `useMemo` for "consistency". Though, as @GoranJakovljevic notes, regular hooks rules apply, so you can always fall back to `React.memo`. If you don't use hooks then just always go with `React.memo`.

Answer (score 6):

**To summarise `React.memo` vs `useMemo` / TLDR:**

**`React.memo`** is a higher-order component (HOC for short) that will memoize a react component based on the props.

```js
export function SomeComponent({ num }) {
  return <p>{num * 10}</p>
}

export default React.memo(SomeComponent, function areEqual(
  prevProps,
  nextProps
) {
  if (prevProps.num !== nextProps.num) {
    return false
  }
  return true
})
```

**`useMemo`** is a react hook that will memoize the value that is returned from the function you provide it.

```js
export function SomeComponent({ num }) {
  const res = useMemo(() => num * 10, [num])
  return <p>{res}</p>
}
```

[Source](https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/react/react-memo-vs-use-memo/)

Answer (score 1):

## React.Memo

Using `React.memo` will cause React to skip rendering a component if its props have not changed.

Example:

```
const Child = React.memo(props => {
  console.log("rendered");
  return <React.Fragment>{props.name}</React.Fragment>;
});

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 1,
    name: "Jioke"
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value + 1
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Child name={this.state.name} />
        <div>{this.state.value}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>+</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

When we click button, `Child` Component does not re-render(`rendered` is displayed only 1)

***Notes:*** The more props, the more calculations, comparison(check is render or not) added comparison cost is not worth it for a "simple" component in terms of render, reconcile, DOM change and side-effect costs. So be careful to decide use it or not

## UseMemo

`useMemo` will cache a value so that it does not need to be recalculated each times components is re-render. It saves return value of function and returns if the inputs are not changed.

Example:

```
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const calculation = useMemo(() => expensiveCalculation(count), [count]);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount((c) => c + 1);
  };
  const addTodo = () => {
    setTodos((t) => [...t, "New Todo"]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>My Todos</h2>
        {todos.map((todo, index) => {
          return <p key={index}>{todo}</p>;
        })}
        <button onClick={addTodo}>Add Todo</button>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div>
        Count: {count}
        <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
        <h2>Expensive Calculation</h2>
        {calculation}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const expensiveCalculation = (num) => {
  console.log("Calculating...");
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    num += 1;
  }
  return num;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

we have an expensive function that runs on every render.
When changing the count or adding a todo, you will notice a delay in execution.
So when we use `useMemo` the expensive function will only run when its dependencies have changed.
In the following example, the expensive function will only run when count is changed and not when todo's are added.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below `simple` example to better understand the answers above. The example demonstrates these scenarios in the simplest way:

- `memo`

  - If the props do not change, the component won't be re-rendered.
- `useMemo`

  - If the dependencies do not change, the component won't be re-rendered.
  - If the dependencies do not change, the function (useful for expensive functions) won't be re-run.

```js
// index.js

import React , { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const Child1 = (props) => {
  console.log("Child1");
  return <p>Child 1</p>;
};

const Child2 = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log("Child2");
  return <p>Child 2</p>;
});

const Child3 = (props) => {
  console.log("Child3");
  return <p>Child 3</p>;
};

const expensiveCalculation = (label) => {
  console.log(label);
  return label;
}; 

function App() {
  console.log("App");

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const child3 = useMemo(() => <Child3 />, []);

  const calculation1 = expensiveCalculation("Expensive calculation without useMemo");
  const calculation2 = useMemo(() => expensiveCalculation("Expensive calculation with useMemo"), []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => {setCount(c => c + 1);}}>Increase count</button>
      <p>Current count: {count}</p>

      <Child1 />
      <Child2 />
      {child3}

      <p>{calculation1}</p>
      <p>{calculation2}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

Input/output:

```
// Initial render
App
Expensive calculation without useMemo
Expensive calculation with useMemo
Child1
Child2
Child3
// Click on the "Increase count" button and observe the impact of memo and useMemo.
App
Expensive calculation without useMemo
Child1
```

Notes:

- I have taken a very simple example to make it easy to explain. Please research a little bit more on the arguments memo and useMemo takes.

Answer (score 0):

In new react documentation said that you can use `useMemo` instead of `memo` https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#memoizing-individual-jsx-nodes

```
export default function TodoList({ todos, tab, theme }) {
      const visibleTodos = useMemo(
          () => filterTodos(todos, tab), [todos, tab]
      );
      const children = useMemo(
          () => <List items={visibleTodos} />, [visibleTodos]
      );
      return (
        <div className={theme}>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
}
```

But, on documentation page you can found:

`Manually wrapping JSX nodes into useMemo is not convenient. For example, you can’t do this conditionally. This is usually why you would wrap components with memo instead of wrapping JSX nodes.`

And it's good to remember that `memo` has a second optional parameter which can be used to compare props and and in some cases re-render component in some not:

`memo(Component, arePropsEqual?)`

https://react.dev/reference/react/memo#memo