# Functional components disappearing with useMemo / React.memo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get my head around `useMemo` (or `React.memo`) to optimize some components rendering.

I'm having an issue I can't explain.

I have the following code:

```
[...]
    const [ cards, setCards ] = useState<Card[]>([])


    function addCard(){
        setCards([...cards, {name: 'card-' + cards.length, counter: 0, type: 'memo'}])
    }

    function onPressCard(index: number){
        cards[index].counter += 1
        setCards([...cards])
    }

   return (
     [...]
    {
      cards.map((x, index) => 
        <Card key={index} {...x} onPress={() => onPressCard(index)}/>
    }
    [...]
)
```

and **Card** defined as

```
const Card: FC<CardProps> = function({ name, counter, onPress }){
    const counterRef = useRef(0)

    const item = useMemo(() => {
        counterRef.current +=1

        return (
        <RectButton onPress={onPress} style={[styles.card, { backgroundColor: 'lightcoral' }]}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{ name }</Text>
            <Text style={styles.counter}> { `counter ${counter}` }</Text>
            <Text style={styles.counter}>{ `render: ${counterRef.current}`}</Text>
        </RectButton>
        )
    }, [name, counter])

    return item
}
```

Why, when i press an item in the list (except the last one), all the following items disappear ? 
[image]

Edit: the same happens with **Card** defined as

```
const areEqual = function(prevProps: Card, nextProps: Card){
    return (
        (prevProps.name === nextProps.name) &&
        (prevProps.counter === nextProps.counter)
    )
}

const Card = React.memo<CardProps>(({ name, counter, onPress }) => {
    const counterRef = useRef(0)

    counterRef.current +=1

    return (
        <RectButton onPress={onPress} style={[styles.card, { backgroundColor: 'lightcoral' }]}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{ name }</Text>
            <Text style={styles.counter}> { `counter ${counter}` }</Text>
            <Text style={styles.counter}>{ `render: ${counterRef.current}`}</Text>
        </RectButton>
        )
}, areEqual)
```

Comment: what does onPressCard do?

Comment: I am not sure useMemo have been designed to memoize whole components. It's quite different from React.memo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55466104/using-usememo-instead-of-react-memo-syntax-issue

Comment: @NicholasTower I updated my question

Comment: @nubinub the same happens when I'm using React.memo with the same comparison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the memoized component includes a reference to an old version of `onPress`. That old `onPress` has an old version of `cards` in its closure. Hitting the button thus calls the old function, which updates the parent's state based on that old state, and that old state has fewer items in it.

One option to fix this is to use the function version of setCards, so that you are basing the update off the latest state. Also, i updated the code to no longer mutate the old card:

```
function onPressCard(index: number){
  setCards(oldCards => {
    const newCards = [...oldCards];
    newCards[index] = {...oldCards[index]};
    newCards[index].counter += 1;
    return newCards;
  })
}
```

Another option is to add onPress to the conditions for useMemo, but since the onPress function changes all the time, you end up not really gaining anything from memoization. This could be improved if onPress itself was memoized, using useCallback:

```
const onPressCard = useCallback((index: number) => {
  cards[index].counter += 1;
  setCards([...cards]);
}, [cards])

// ...

const item = useMemo(() => {
  counterRef.current +=1

  return ( /* jsx omitted for brevity */ )
}, [name, counter, onPress])
```

Comment: Perfect, could you just show an example using `useCallback` ? Not sure how to go about that one

Comment: @Orelus I've added that in. UseCallback is very similar to useMemo., it just assumes you want to memoize a function. `useCallback(() => 'hello world')` is identical to `useMemo(() => () => 'hello world')`;