# Why React renders a component even though I don't pass anything to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the code :

**APP.JS**

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import Counter from './components/Counter';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [countA, setCountA] = useState(0);
  const incrementA = () => {
    setCountA(countA + 1);
  };


  // const memoCounter = useMemo(() => {
  //   return <Counter />;
  // }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Incrementing CountA from APP.JS : {countA}</h1>
      <p>
        <button onClick={incrementA}>Increment A</button>
      </p>
      {/* {memoCounter} */}

      <Counter />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Counter.js :**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
let renderCount = 1;
const Counter = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    renderCount++;
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Rendering Counter component : {renderCount}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

When the user hits the button and increments , React renders `Counter` component all over again , even though I don't pass anything to it.

However when I put `useMemo` it doesn't.

Why ?

Comment: "React renders Counter component all over again , even though I don't pass anything to it." Do you mean it is rendered twice after each click? If yes than it is likely because you have `StrictMode` wrapper around your `<App />`.

Comment: Also `setCountA(countA + 1);` is not recommended way to do state updates that are dependent on previous state. Use callback `setCountA(count => count + 1);`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: No strict mode , I've checked it already.

Comment: Then it should be rendered once on every click. This is how react works: always rerender unless you manually memoize things.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-feistel-6cuxi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when a parent component renders (`App`), it renders **all** its children (`Counter`).

To overload the default behaviour, use React API like [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

```
const Counter = () => {...}
export default React.memo(Counter);
```

Comment: I've used `UseMemo` , what's the deal between `memo` and `useMemo` ?

Comment: They not related, check their API description, and there is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55466104/using-usememo-instead-of-react-memo-syntax-issue

Comment: But OP haven't passing any prop to counter, it shouldn't render twice after click the button.

Comment: Ofc it does, check your self. Even if the props the same, the default behaviour is what I mentioned. Twice is probably because of StrictMode, check the codesandbox in comments

Comment: ok, the reason is OP put button in the parent. Usually we will put it in child component rather then the parent. As it set the parent state after click so all the parent rerender.